# How to get the Index of First Character from a string contains numeric values using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the index of First ever character appear in the string.

for example : I have a string  " 225 get first character " 
In this I want the index of 'g' .how to get this ?

thanks

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at RegExpressions?

Comment: @reporter ..Can you help me out with this one ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var str = " 225 get first character ";
var index = /[a-z]/i.exec(str).index;
alert(index); // 5
```

Comment: it will return 4..anyways it helped me :)

Comment: It returns 5 on latest Firefox.

Comment: This is a regex literal case insensitive `/i` search for English letters, returning a zero based index of the match in string.  Very nice!

Answer (score 8):

You may use a regular expression:

```
var str = " 225 get first character ";
var firstChar = str.match('[a-zA-Z]');
//'g'
```

And if you want the index,

```
var index = str.indexOf(firstChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified [@Jorgeblom answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489481/10591472):

```
var str = "  255 get first character";
var firstCharIndex = str.match('[a-zA-Z]').index;

console.log(firstCharIndex);
// 6
```

The `match()` function return a array with following values:

- [0] - First matching character => "g"
- [index] - Index of the first match => 6
- [input] - the whole input string
- [groups] - empty in these case. If you declare grouped regex conditions, these groups will be listed here with the matching results

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`var str = " 225 get first character ";

var first_char = str.search(/[a-zA-Z]/);`