# First occurence of any character

Tags: javascript, regex

I know how to find the first occurence of a predefined character like so `a.indexOf("R")` but what if you would like to find the first occurence of any character A-Z, say that my string contains digits and other special characters and I'm only interested in a "normal" letter?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489407/how-to-get-the-index-of-first-character-from-a-string-contains-numeric-values-us

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```
a.match(/[A-Za-z]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
var a = " $#714 Abcd";
answer = a.match(/[A-Za-z]/)[0]
console.log(answer); // 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in order to match this expression:

```
a.match(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/)
```

This will check whether the first character is alphabet and then the rest to be alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

This function will return an array with the positions in the string of all the first occurrence of any letter:

```
var s = 'asdlkn akn dlkandl nl ndvds';

function getFirstOccurrenceOffset(s) {
    s = s.split("").reverse().join(""); // reverse the string
    var re = /([A-Z])(?!.*\1)/gi;
    var m;
    var result = Array();
    while ((m = re.exec(s)) !== null)
        result.push(s.length - m.index - 1);

    return result.reverse();
}

console.log(getFirstOccurrenceOffset(s));
```

The function is case insensitive, but you can remove the i modifier to make it case sensitive.